# MS-Access: HAVING clause not returning any records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Select query to extract Customer Names and Purchase Dates from a table. My goal is to select only those names and dates for customers who have ordered on more than one distinct date. My code is as follows:

```
SELECT Customer, PurchDate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PurchDate, Customer
      FROM (SELECT CDate(FORMAT(DateAdd("h",-7,Mid([purchase-date],1,10)+""+Mid([purchase-date],12,8)), "Short Date")) AS PurchDate,
                 [buyer-name] AS Customer
            FROM RawImport
            WHERE sku ALIKE "%RE%"))
GROUP BY Customer, PurchDate
HAVING COUNT(PurchDate)>1
ORDER BY PurchDate
```

This returns no results, even though there are many customers with more than one Purchase Date. The inner two Selects work perfectly and return a set of distinct dates for each customer, so I believe there is some problem in my GROUP/HAVING/ORDER clauses.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What are your results when you remove the HAVING clause?

Comment: All the same info that I get from the inner selects, just arranged differently due to the order of my select and the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing in the inner select

```
SELECT DISTINCT PurchDate, Customer
```

and in the outter select

```
GROUP BY Customer, PurchDate
```

That mean all are

```
having count(*) = 1
```

I cant give you the exact sintaxis in access but you need something like this

I will use `YourTable` as a replacement of your inner derivated table to make it easy to read

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer, PurchDate 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE Customer IN (
                    SELECT Customer
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Customer, PurchDate 
                          FROM YourTable)
                    GROUP BY Customer
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                  )
```

- inner select will give you which customer order on more than one day.
- outside select will bring you those customer on all those days.

.

Maybe you can try something simple to get the list of customer who brought in more than one day like this

```
SELECT [buyer-name]
FROM RawImport
WHERE sku ALIKE "%RE%"
GROUP BY [buyer-name]
HAVING Format(MAX(purchase-date,"DD/MM/YYYY")) <> 
       Format(MIN(purchase-date,"DD/MM/YYYY"))
```

Comment: Do you mean GROUP BY Customer only in the outer select? Then I get the error that PurchDate is not part of an aggregate function

Comment: And I see what you mean about the SELECT DISTINCT. I've tried to write the code without it `Select Customer, PurchDate
FROM (SELECT PurchDate, Customer
    FROM (SELECT CDate(FORMAT(DateAdd("h",-7,Mid([purchase-date],1,10)+" "+Mid([purchase-date],12,8)), "Short Date")) AS PurchDate, [buyer-name] AS Customer
        FROM RawImport
        WHERE sku ALIKE "%FR%")
   GROUP BY PurchDate, Customer)
GROUP BY Customer, PurchDate
HAVING COUNT(PurchDate)>1
ORDER BY PurchDate` But I still get the same no-records result.

Comment: Thank you, your final code did return the results I was looking for!